# Virtuemart3.0 payment method issue for multiple language

Tags: virtuemart

I have a issue related to virtuemart
my site is in multiple language so payment method is displaying ony for english langusge in cart.
for other language payment method option is not displaying on cart
I am getting a error message("Sorry, none of the payment methods suits the characteristics of your order. You're welcome")
please help me
virtuemart version is 3.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed it myself.
Actually, I was missing some settings in virtue mart admin section.
We have to setup payment method and shipping method for each language separately.